# Python - Newspaper Library - Why is it missing sizable portions of articles?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, nlp, python-newspaper

I'm using the newspaper library, V. 2.7 found [here](http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

When I download, parse, and print the text, it gives me a much smaller portion of the article than exists in reality. Why is this? Is there any way to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
from newspaper import Article

url = "http://www.nytimes.com/2010/10/07/us/politics/07manchin.html"

article_object = Article(url, language = 'en')
article_object.download()
article_object.parse()
article_object.text
```

If you look at what it prints out, and **[compares with the actual article online](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/10/07/us/politics/07manchin.html)**, one finds that the article.text skips over the first 7-8 paragraphs of the actual article. Any way to make sure the "full" article is captured?

Here's the output of article_object.text:

> u'The national Republican Party has smelled blood and is spending
>   millions on television ads here as part of its drive to retake the
>   Senate. One new ad shows men in baseball caps predicting that Mr.
>   Manchin will transform into \u201cWashington Joe,\u201d declaring,
>   \u201cWe\u2019ve got to stop Obama.\u201d\n\nPhoto\n\nMr. Manchin
>   thought he had punched all the right buttons in this state with a
>   Democratic majority but conservative values. He won his second term as
>   governor in 2008 with 70 percent of the vote and has garnered praise
>   for fiscal responsibility; even Mr. Raese calls him a good governor.
>   He has been endorsed by the Chamber of Commerce, the National Rifle
>   Association and both the coal industry and the mine workers.\n\nMr.
>   Manchin is highlighting his conservative credentials and record of
>   independence and he has accused his opponent of waging a campaign of
>   \u201cfear and smear.\u201d But the anti-Obama message appears to be
>   resonating with some residents \u2014 perhaps the same voters who gave
>   the state to Senator John McCain and President Bush in the last three
>   presidential elections.\n\n\u201cManchin has been a great governor,
>   but I\u2019m going to vote for Raese,\u201d said Jeff Whittington, 41,
>   a tire distributor in Charleston. \u201cI think Manchin will get to
>   the Senate and be a rubber stamp for Obama,\u201d he said, repeating
>   Mr. Raese\u2019s message almost word for word.\n\nIn a state where
>   coal is seen as the fount of prosperity, Mr. Raese has seized on what
>   he calls ambiguous statements by Mr. Manchin on proposals for a
>   cap-and-trade system to reduce greenhouse gases. Mr. Manchin now
>   speaks clearly on the issue: he is firmly against cap-and-trade and a
>   carbon tax, he emphasized in the interview.\n\nOn Wednesday, Mr.
>   Manchin had an opportunity to underscore his support for coal and to
>   distance himself from the president. With the head of the coal
>   producers\u2019 association at his side in the state Capitol, he
>   announced that the state was suing two federal agencies, seeking to
>   reverse the stricter controls on mountain-top coal mining adopted in
>   2009 by the Obama administration.\n\nAdvertisement Continue reading
>   the main story\n\nDiscussing the suit against the Environmental
>   Protection Agency and the Army Corps of Engineers, Mr. Manchin said
>   that the more stringent procedures were unlawful and had harmed the
>   state by slowing new mining projects to a trickle, and he accused the
>   Obama administration of trying \u201cto destroy our coal industry and
>   way of life.\u201d\n\nThe E.P.A. responded that its actions were
>   legally and scientifically sound.\n\nMr. Manchin, independent experts
>   and even the West Virginia Coal Association have taken exception to a
>   Raese ad accusing Mr. Manchin of passing a state law that
>   \u201celiminates 25 percent of coal usage in our power
>   plants.\u201d\n\nIn fact, the law calls for progress in new energy
>   technologies that include cleaner coal, and it had the support of the
>   industry.\n\nMr. Raese has also lambasted the governor for past
>   statements welcoming the Obama health plan; Mr. Manchin says that some
>   core elements of the plan, like protecting children\u2019s coverage,
>   are good but that others should be repealed. Mr. Raese calls the
>   health plan \u201cpure, unadulterated socialism\u201d that should be
>   discarded entirely, a message that appeals to many small-business
>   owners.\n\nPhoto\n\nMr. Raese is a brawny and self-confident man who
>   has run unsuccessfully for the Senate and for governor before and now
>   feels currents flowing his way. \u201cHow do you put together a
>   business plan when you have Obamacare facing you, when you\u2019ve got
>   cap-and-trade facing you?\u201d he asked in an interview at the
>   Republican office in Morgantown, his home base.\n\nMr. Raese runs
>   limestone mines and a steel-fabrication company and is part owner of a
>   radio network and a newspaper. He has at least three homes around the
>   country, and his wife lives in their home in Palm Beach, Fla., while
>   he has kept his residence in West Virginia.\n\nWhile Mr. Raese\u2019s
>   anti-Washington message has wide appeal, his unequivocal support for
>   Nafta and free trade and his opposition to unions may not help him in
>   a state with a blue-collar heritage. Mr. Manchin\u2019s campaign has
>   run ads featuring Mr. Raese boasting about his inherited wealth and
>   highlighting his opposition to minimum wages and other worker
>   protections.\n\nIn interviews across the state, some residents said
>   that while Mr. Raese can seem arrogant, they admired his record of
>   creating jobs and were ready to send a new face to Washington rather
>   than elect a man they see as a career politician.\n\nAdvertisement
>   Continue reading the main story\n\nThe only polls published so far
>   were automated \u2014 done without personal interviews \u2014 and are
>   not widely accepted as reliable. But private polling by both camps
>   indicates an unexpectedly close race.\n\nFord Frances, 53, a lawyer in
>   Charleston, said he likes Mr. Manchin as governor \u2014 Mr. Manchin
>   will retain his job if he loses the Senate race \u2014 but that he is
>   leaning toward voting for Mr. Raese because he worries about a
>   skyrocketing federal deficit and thinks government has too big a role
>   in the economy.\n\nOthers, including Cheryl Bonner, 64, of Fairmont,
>   said they thought it was unfair to paint Mr. Manchin with the excesses
>   of Washington. \u201cHe\u2019s been for West Virginia, and I\u2019m
>   leaning toward voting for him,\u201d said Ms. Bonner, who had to start
>   working again, as a store clerk, because her and her husband\u2019s
>   Social Security and pension checks did not cover the bills. She hopes
>   that retirees will be protected, whoever wins, she said.\n\nSome
>   residents said Mr. Manchin was just unlucky to be running for national
>   office this year. \u201cProbably at any other time he\u2019d have
>   gotten my vote,\u201d said a 51-year-old credit analyst in Charleston,
>   an economic conservative who voted for Mr. Manchin in 2008 but is
>   troubled by the administration\u2019s economic
>   policies.\n\n\u201cPutting him in that Senate seat would enhance the
>   Democrats\u2019 position,\u201d said the man, who declined to give his
>   name because his company has dealings with the governor\u2019s office.
>   \u201cWe\u2019d rather keep him here as governor.\u201d'

Comment: The code doesn't print anything /c:

Comment: This looks like a bug with the library. See [this issue](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/issues/128) for similar cases.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks for the link. That helps.